# Нестатический метод не видит нестатическое поле того же TypeScript-класса, когда вызывается из декоратора

Tags: typescript, декоратор

Приведённую ниже функцию планируется использовать как декоратор для методов наследников класса `Controller`:

```
function RouteHandler(route: Router.Route): (controller: Controller, methodName: string) => void {

  return (controller: Controller, methodName: string): void => {

    /* В данном случае, "methodName" должен быть у инстанса "controller" покуда `RouteHandler`
       используется по назначению. */
    const handler: Router.RouteHandler =
        (controller as unknown as { [methodName: string]: Router.RouteHandler; })[methodName];

    controller.setRouterAndHandlerPair(route, handler);
  };
}
```

Эта функция-декоратор должна сохранить объект `route` и соответствующий ей обработчик маршрута в поле `routesAndHandlersMap` наследника класса`Controller`:

```
class Controller {

  private readonly routesAndHandlersMap: Map<Router.Route, Router.RouteHandler> = new Map<Router.Route, Router.RouteHandler>();

  public setRouterAndHandlerPair(route: Router.Route, handler: Router.RouteHandler): void {
    this.routesAndHandlersMap.set(route, handler);
  }

  public getRoutesAndHandlers(): Array<[ Router.Route, Router.RouteHandler ]> {
    return Array.from(this.routesAndHandlersMap.entries());
  }
}
```

Использовать декторатор планируется примерно так:

```
class ProductsController extends Controller {

  @RouteHandler({
    type: HTTP_Methods.get,
    pathTemplate: "api/products"
  })
  private async retrieveSelection(_request: Request, response: Response): Promise<void> {
    // ...
  }
}
```

### Проблема

Когда я создаю инстанс класса `ProductController` (унаследованного от `Сontroller`):

```
const productController: ProductsController = new ProductsController();
```

`RouteHandler` вызывает `controller.setRouterAndHandlerPair(route, handler);`, а тот в свою очередь вызывает`this.routesAndHandlersMap.set(route, handler);`, но `this.routesAndHandlersMap` по неизвестной мне причине имеет значение `undefined`. Это порождает ошибку `TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined`.

Очень похоже на то, что ссылка не на тот `this`. Такое обычно происходит, когда вместо вызова функции указывают ссылку на на неё (например `this.exampleFuntion1` вместо `this.exampleFunction1()`), но в данном случае проблема в `this` стала для меня неожиданной. Согласно выводу в консоль, `this` имеет значение `ProductsController: {}` в `setRouterAndHandlerPair`.

### Как будет использован метод `getRoutesAndHandlers`

Класс `Server` берёт на себя создание инстансов контроллеров и вызов `getRoutesAndHandlers` у каждого из них. Всё. что остаётся сделать пользователю класса `Server` - указать в свойстве `routing` ссылки на классы контроллеров, которых в реальном приложении несколько:

```
Server.initializeAndStart({
  host: "127.0.0.1",
  port: 1337,
  routing: [ ProductsController, ProductsCategoriesController ],
  logger: ConsoleApplicationLogger
});
```

[Полный листинг](https://www.staging-typescript.org/play?ts=4.2.3&ssl=40&ssc=5&pln=40&pc=51#code/PTAEF5NAFAnBTAtAgjgVwJYILbwHbwAuAzpGeRZVdTbXfQ-QLABQIoinoASgPZqF4sUADM0eAMaEMvPAEMANhkIBPDpw2at2nbr36Dhoztb402UAAkAKtegB9ALJEAFrwAmxUAG9WoUADmRBCgAEQA4gCi1qEANH6gAA68xIQhodAA8gDKMQns+PwBeKK8wni8AO6sAL6srPK4xIlyEvA8-ILCviwJ8AAeybBpqontfALwxACCeO6WcnMKQsSOcokha4kAPBOCsR2TC0tCAHz1LP4DQyMqY4eCIT3+-qPwAFxWtg7OhG6eAG4Ev4Wn9rPBsIkFHJBJ9UrAMHgAkDLi90EIVNA5LA5LgusQAPyfbygADaLRxeKEADlcR9QPDEQEALpwwgIpEA0A1FH+HkXK6DMq3e57eBrQgSFxPYGgFyLdzLWCfMXHRVCXkvWCdeBYylEFYqnV6un4zX83qo67C0BvB7wNVKkIACll-lQaCmhBV8HRqQOCGasmI9O4U2SeBDAeN2NNhvtJqpsGICQAlBBTjBtdgMCHtgA3XgYdynFF9IXDW13cYx-X4p5kgDW8BUbI5LLbTK5FrqbDAxgHg6Hw5Ho+0Fwk0OIXgAwrJ2bwFE6eglEgj8zD2gg5O5ZAo1NrJjM5o6VltPltdjrYAA6MUHMW31UKpWZ8CgAiVUCXx93nUP68-yOF8zmdVMy1RRI0AAIyUCQGSIR9ZnmEDYCxLBnUPWF7Sff85VQo1Jlw4CTlgVNPkLYsfFlCRg0XeAbwUXgAmdUINFCcCaLo5ZGOY50-lzTjUX8WjI3o3iWIE4gbywqZkNPZMtnA0B2HEdx4BERF4HcUAAEJ9NlKSZJ1Y8UNI1Z1hvENCEwvD5VIoS+QFJIYLgwJEJM+TUOIMDPmmWAcRUbZSRwoD9lC59SNAZlM2eLUiDQWASn8wKbxEbN+JcXNjKPLzzK2G98HZDApjAxzuVqC5WDESRpFke0FNsyZCK6ML4HI0BnVEhclyET45zwHqlQOPF-lpXBOyRdNwEzSidJXVEEEIRKSi6+dtV65VQAGoahBG1wPHG+lGSmiiix0mbqMtF4VIAKlAQAUBlAawXHgMo1EAVAZQAASRKKTQAkOQo1tV6wlGw66VCUBsDQVJQGg9pETCbqNqVKHEVSRY2lAIHQCYpEca8f6aqkGQSlzeH4CZWV7pu2HtMJ0B1NonFCDKUphFCHbUaEdG8FehE2dvUBbuALjIzSez1S239IuliA3ReNbBp54RcfERsKkqEpcZJUlwfcI7Jo7CKdQU7tU31g7DbpZkIJulHFyVKyPKIvLpfQ2AmvCqWlXKnsJynLw4A8NApGIbmnaEUABkEOZZ3WqPumcgABOWlWdOLXmrT4bDsJxrekoJCHiYSkhhFxwUhaFsNCdYMGANdQ-D0IEhqVNV3XTdCZUSRQCWhF4HzeBsngZZSdkZ17A9L0fT9Ev+-DYNQyXyN2s+EOczzObYtldgbwPtvKstVhRLhpv3DDwhI82jftUv8Ob6dd9PyzZuSCfoQwJRIA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае неверное используются [параметры декоратора](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#method-decorators):

> Первым параметром передается **не** создаваемый объект, а **прототип** этого объекта.

Так как поле `routesAndHandlersMap` расположено непосредственно в объекте, а не в прототипе и возникает указанная ошибка.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124901/discussion-on-answer-by-grundy-------).

Answer (score -1):

У вас `routesAndHandlersMap` поле объявлено как `private`, а значит оно доступно только внутри того класса, в котором обьявлено.

Для того, чтобы поле было доступно внутри потомка (т.е в данном случае внутри ProductsController), следует использовать для него модификатор `protected`

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ. К сожалению он не верен в чём Вы можете убедиться, изменив `private` на `protected` в TypeScript playground (ссылка в конце вопроса). Не сработает это потому, что модификаторы TypeScript на компилированный JavaScript никак не влияют.